# Adding Current Date and Time in AWK pattern match with Wildcard

Tags: ksh, aix

I have this logging string that I want to search for:

```
[Nov 18, 2019 8:53:36 AM] ProcessFlow RMI Server started at: 10.155.166.24:16003
```

I want to trap the month day, year and the string "RMI Server started"

I'm not having luck with this in AIX commandline:

```
$awk '$0 ~ /(date "+%b %d, %Y")*RMI Server started/' /lsf10/law/system/pfrmi.log
```

NOTE: it does capture the RMI Server Started - but all the dates of this  message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is the `date` call, while calling from within the `awk` script is doable, it's going to be easier if we make the call in `ksh`, store the result in a `ksh` variable, and then pass this variable into `awk` using the `-v` option.

Second issue is the mixing of a (`awk`) variable and a regex for pattern matching; I find it's a bit easier to build a regex pattern first and then use said pattern for the actual pattern matching.

But first some data ... assuming 'today' is 23 March 2021:

```
$ cat pfrmi.log
[Mar  9, 2019 8:53:36 AM] ProcessFlow RMI Server started at: 10.155.166.24:16003   - skip this line
[Mar 23, 2021 8:53:36 AM] ProcessFlow RMI Server started at: 10.155.166.24:16003   - pick this line
[Nov 18, 2019 8:53:36 AM] some other  TOT Server started at: 10.155.166.24:16003   - skip this line
[Mar 23, 2021 8:53:36 AM] ProcessFlow RMI Server started at: 10.155.166.24:16003   - pick this line
  [Mar 23, 2021 8:53:36 AM] ProcessFlow RMI Server started at: 10.155.166.24:16003 - skip this line
[Nov 18, 2020 8:53:36 AM] ProcessFlow RMI Server started at: 10.155.166.24:16003   - skip this line
```

Now the proposed code:

```
$ today=$(date '+%b %d, %Y')
$ echo "${today}"
Mar 23, 2021

$ awk -v today="${today}" '                            # pass ksh variable into awk
BEGIN    { ptn="^[[]"today" .*RMI Server started" }    # build our regex pattern
$0 ~ ptn                                               # test current line against our regex and if it matches the line will be passed to stdout
' pfrmi.log
```

For my sample data file this generates:

```
[Mar 23, 2021 8:53:36 AM] ProcessFlow RMI Server started at: 10.155.166.24:16003 - pick this line
[Mar 23, 2021 8:53:36 AM] ProcessFlow RMI Server started at: 10.155.166.24:16003 - pick this line
```

Collapsing the `awk` into a single-line command and removing the comments:

```
awk -v today="${today}" 'BEGIN { ptn="^[[]"today" .*RMI Server started" } $0 ~ ptn' pfrmi.log
```